# Creating Formulas with Loops in Google Sheets that increment Cell References

Tags: google-sheets

So, I basically have a lookup sheet that is ever-changing in which I have various IP Addresses that I list in a dropdown list box. Depending on the selection made, I want to automate the lookup for several other fields.  When I just had 3 IP addresses, i was able to accomplish this task with the formula:

`=IF(P4 = 'Lookup Values'!B3, 'Lookup Values'!D3, if(P4 ='Lookup Values'!B4, 'Lookup Values'!D4, if(P4 = 'Lookup Values'!B5, 'Lookup Values'!D5)))`

This is far from elegant and was fine for just 3 items, however a pain in the rear to update as my Lookup Values list is now about 15 IP addresses (and growing).  I'm sure there's a better way to do this or perhaps a function that allows me to quickly loop through the data, find a corresponding match and then fill in an associated field.

The logic is just if P4 has a value, then it should lookup to find which item in the B column and populate this cell with the corresponding number from the D column.

Any thoughts or guidance would be highly appreciated.  My brain just isn't thinking clearly.  I've seen a number of loops but most of those had math functions involved and not necessarily cell references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Some Approaches

#### VLOOKUP

```
=VLOOKUP(P4, 'Lookup Values'!B3:D, 3, 0)
```

#### FILTER

```
=FILTER('Lookup Values'!D3:D,
        'Lookup Values'!B3:B=P4)
```

#### ARRAYFORMULA

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
   IF('Lookup Values'!B3:B=P4,
      'Lookup Values'!D3:D,))
```

## Function Support

[ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en)  [FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en)  [VLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en)

Comment: Thank you so much... 3 obvious answers are better than 1 as well.  Time for me to go back and read the manual apparently.  :)

Comment: @2Advanced My pleasure! I learnt so much on this site from other more experienced users  Stick around learn, and then answer other people's questions who are starting on the same path. Be well!